# Making a drag and drop cube game

Tags: jquery, svg, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to make a drag and drop game where you choose one of 3 cubes and drop it on a plane 4x4 in isometric. When droped, the cubes in front should be over the cubes behind and they should snap to the grid. I used the tutorial on http://www.elated.com/articles/drag-and-drop-with-jquery-your-essential-guide/ for the basics but I can't reach all of the functionalities.

[image: Here's one cube being dragged on the grid plane]

How can I do this and are there any usefull resources that I could use?

```
</script>
  $( init1 );
  function init1() {
    $('#makeMeDraggable1').draggable( {
      containment: '#gameFull',
      cursor: 'move',
      snap: '#gameFull',
      helper: 'clone'
    } );
  }

  $( init2 );
  function init2() {
    $('#makeMeDraggable2').draggable( {
      containment: '#gameFull',
      cursor: 'move',
      snap: '#gameFull',
      helper: 'clone'
    } );
  }
  $( init3 );
  function init3() {
    $('#makeMeDraggable3').draggable( {
      containment: '#gameFull',
      cursor: 'move',
      snap: '#gameFull',
      helper: 'clone'
    } );
  }
</script>

<div id="gameFull">
  <div class="drop_game">
    <img src="/wordpress/wp-content/themes/cubic/img/one_game.svg">
  </div>

  <div class="cubic_one_game">
    <div>
      <img id="makeMeDraggable1" class="singleCube" src="/wordpress/wp-
content/themes/cubic/img/cube_one_1.svg">
      <p>moduł kuchenny</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img id="makeMeDraggable2" class="singleCube" src="/wordpress/wp-content/themes/cubic/img/cube_one_1.svg">
      <p>moduł sypialniany</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img id="makeMeDraggable3" class="singleCube" src="/wordpress/wp-content/themes/cubic/img/cube_one_1.svg">
      <p>moduł łazienkowy</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Show us how far you've got and exactly which feature you're stuck on.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/bo91p71q/1/ I didn't go far, just the basic. I'm stuck on the general idea. How to drop the elements on the grid so it snaps to the grid (which is an svg image). How not to drop it on populated cell. How to pick it up from a cell to put it in another.

Comment: Too broad, focus on one thing or the question will end up closed. Please puy your working in the question i.e. not (just) a link to a jsfiddle and especially not just a link to a jsfiddle in a comment.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I tried to follow your instructions and changed the question.